# Xcode run script to delete all files in a folder

Tags: ios, xcode, run-script

I want to delete all files inside "container" folder in the project directory.
I have tried this linux script in Xcode **runscript**. But it does not work.

```
rm -r "${SRCROOT}/container/*"
```

If i use rm -r "${SRCROOT}/container/", it will delete including the folder. I only want to delete the files inside the folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your `Run Script` to be the following:

```
rm -rf "${SRCROOT}"/container/*
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer